# Get information about all rows from one table, when in join table that row is not

Tags: mysql, sql

How obtain in case that in table userItems is not record joined with moduleItems just null?

```
SELECT `users`.*, `useritems`.*, `moduleitems`.*, `modulesubitems`.* FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `useritems` ON useritems.f_user_id = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN `moduleitems` ON moduleitems.moduleItem_id = useritems.f_moduleItem_id
LEFT JOIN `modulesubitems` ON modulesubitems.modulesubitem_id = useritems.userItem_value
```

Edit: **My DB structure**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `moduleitems` (
`moduleItem_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`f_module_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`moduleItem_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=63 ;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `modules` (
`module_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`module_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `modulesubitems` (
`moduleSubitem_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`f_moduleItem_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`moduleSubitem_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=19 ;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `useritems` (
`f_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`f_moduleItem_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`userItem_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`f_user_id`,`f_moduleItem_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=35 ;
```

Comment: *How obtain in case that in table userItems is not record joined with moduleItems just null* -- hard to understand.

Comment: What is the question? Excuseme, but I can't understand it...

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. If you have 10 moduleItems (subitems are not important now) and one moduleItem was added after insert user, so in userItems are just 9 userItems. I need to get 10 userItems, last one with null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are would like to see every moduleitem for each user, regardless if they have a matching record in the useritems table, this should work:

```
SELECT  `users`.*, `useritems`.*, `moduleitems`.*, `modulesubitems`.* 

FROM    `users`

        CROSS JOIN `moduleitems`

        LEFT JOIN `useritems` 
        ON useritems.f_user_id = users.user_id
        AND moduleitems.moduleItem_id = useritems.f_moduleItem_id

        LEFT JOIN `modulesubitems` 
        ON modulesubitems.modulesubitem_id = useritems.userItem_value
```

Comment: Unknown column 'useritems.userItem_value' in 'on clause'

Comment: Unfortunately no. Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: You got me there.  You have users.user_id in the query you posted, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work.  Post your table structures if you would like more help.

Comment: Ok, try it now.  I added CROSS JOIN to the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find all records that are not in a joined table (when using a LEFT JOIN), add to your WHERE clause where the field you are joining in that table is NULL.  All the fields in the joining table will be NULL if there is no match.

For example this would work if you are trying to find cases where there is no match in the moduleitems table.:

```
SELECT `users`.*, `useritems`.*, `moduleitems`.*, `modulesubitems`.* 
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `useritems` ON useritems.f_user_id = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN `moduleitems` ON moduleitems.moduleItem_id = useritems.f_moduleItem_id
LEFT JOIN `modulesubitems` ON modulesubitems.modulesubitem_id = useritems.userItem_value
WHERE moduleitems.moduleItem_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Of course if you were looking for cases where there is no match on moduleitems, you would not need the subsequent join to modulesubitems and also `moduleitems`.*, `modulesubitems`.*.

Comment: In moduleitems and modulesubitems are that records. They aren´t in table userItems (when is adden new moduleItem after insert new user). Your query return empty result.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are trying to do.  If you want to see where there are no useritems, change the WHERE clause to useritems.f_user_id IS NULL.  However since you are joining from that table to moduleitems and then modulesubitems, you will not get any matching records in those table.

Comment: WHERE nothing change. When records are not there without WHERE, they will not with WHERE as well.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now.  So for each user, you want to show all module items regardless if they have a match in the useritems table?